# Multi-image UICollectionView cell placement

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

In the above image, I am trying to get the cell with tip #NOFILTER to be adjacent to the profile image cell and below the "GO BOLD" tip cell.

Here is my code setting this up currently:

```
extension ProfileImagesSignupView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: conf.edgeInsetPadding, left: conf.edgeInsetPadding, bottom: conf.edgeInsetPadding, right: conf.edgeInsetPadding)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itm = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.item]
    switch itm{
    case .profile, .profileItem(_):
         var dimen: CGFloat = self.collectionView.frame.width - (2 * conf.edgeInsetPadding)
         let smallDimen = (dimen - (conf.itemsPerRow - 1) * conf.minimumInterItemSpacing) / conf.itemsPerRow

         dimen -= smallDimen
         dimen -= (conf.itemsPerRow - 2) * conf.minimumInterItemSpacing

         return CGSize(width: dimen, height: dimen)
    default:
        var dimen: CGFloat = self.collectionView.frame.width - (2 * conf.edgeInsetPadding)


        dimen = (dimen - (conf.itemsPerRow - 1) * conf.minimumInterItemSpacing) / conf.itemsPerRow
        //Small precision error causes issue, so a small subtraction in order to fix cell alignment
        dimen = dimen - CGFloat(0.05)
        return CGSize(width: dimen, height: dimen)
    }
}
}
```

Anyone have any idea what is missing here in order to get that item moved over?

EDIT: I currently use LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout to support drag n drop capabilities here.

Comment: try it https://github.com/ahmedAlmasri/SNCollectionViewLayout

Comment: To get what you want you can't use a standard flow layout.

Comment: @a.masri I currently use LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout (added to post with an edit) to support drag n drop capabilities.  If I fork your project and make it subclass this, could it possibly have both darg n drop and the ability to format the collection like i need?  (trying to support drag n drop on pre-iOS 11 as well)

Comment: @daredevil1234 Yes, you can fork my project and add any custom feature, 

Note : the drag drop feature on collectionview not related the flowlayout

Comment: @a.masri to support drag n drop pre iOS 11 when the dragDelegate and dropDelegate were introduced, it was typically supported via custom layouts classes

Comment: if you need use drag drop look it https://hackernoon.com/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

Comment: @a.masri yes, as stated in my TWO previous comments, I need to support drag n drop PRE-iOS 11.  thanks anyway though